# Broken DAG: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: airflow

I have this snippet of code where it's delivering the error :

```
airflow_dir=Variable.get("airflow_dir")

#keys = yaml.safe_load(open(airflow_dir+'dags/config/keys.yml').read())
dagConfig = yaml.safe_load(open(airflow_dir+'dags/config/dw_base_gerencial_diaria_matinal.yml').read())

def represent_none(self, _):
    return self.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:null', '')

yaml.add_representer(type(None), represent_none)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'retries': 3
}
```

when run:

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/dw_base_gerencial_diaria_matinal.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/dw_base_gerencial_diaria_matinal.py", line 18, in <module>
    dagConfig = yaml.safe_load(open(airflow_dir+'dags/config/dw_base_gerencial_diaria_matinal.yml').read())
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/prado/Downloads/Desenvolvimento_pes/Airflow/dags/config/dw_base_gerencial_diaria_matinal.yml'
```

The file path is correct and the file exists within the directory.

The yaml.safe_load has the correct path and still displays the msg

I'm using Airflow on Windows with Docker.

I don't know if I need some kind of permission for Airflow to access this directory.

Comment: Setting Variable.get as top level code is a very bad idea

Comment: old legacy i'm trying to improve